# Best FTP Server Architecture for 1000s of users

Tags: ftp, load-balancing

We have a shared hosting platform. Our users need to connect to their FTP accounts on the main machine. Main machine is a gigantic computer with infinite CPU and RAM

What would be the best design to allow FTP Connections on there ?

- create an LDAP on top, haproxy on another server and create a farm of ftp servers behind it NFS'ing to main server with correct user permissions?

This is kind of only thing I can think of, do you have a more practical solution where i can just get this done on the main server ?

Comment: Where can I get one of those computers with infinite CPU and RAM?

Comment: Indeed...if you throw 2 NICs and decent internet connection on the main server that'd be all you would need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be DNS roundrobining multiple FTP hosts. Then using NFS, mount the drives over the network.

You could then set up PureFTPd with mySQL/whatever authentication. To be honest here the main problem on this is not the amount of users - since with plenty of RAM a half-decent ftp daemon will scale well - but on I/O  for your disks. That is likely to be the biggest bottleneck. It's all well and good having dual gigabit NICs for internet available, but pretty useless if your HDDs top out at under a gigabit.